# Contextual menu entry - struggling with command

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, registry

I'd like to be able to right click on a computer in the Windows Network and connect to it using VNC.  I made the registry entries in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\NetServer\shell\RemoteVNC\command

The menu shows up when right clicking on a network computer but I'm struggling with the command.  I currently have

```
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe" %1
```

the /k to keep the window open while i figure this out.  I'm trying to pass the %1 which ends up being

```
//computer-name
```

which is causing problems. Is it possible to remove these slashes in a one line registry entry?  I just need vncviewer.exe appended with a space and hostname but I'm stuck on the slashes.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Write a program that removes the backslashes then calls vncviewer.

Comment: That helps a little.  My registry value now passes %1 to a batch file... looks like a have some fiddling to do still

Answer (score 0):

Made a batch file that takes care of this!

```
@echo off
cd c:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\
SET host=%1
vncviewer.exe %host:~2%
```